# R function to make new column based on previous values in the same colums

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I'm having trouble trying to convert an Excel formula into R.  The Excel table looks like this:

```
 Year   V1    V2
 2012          1
 2013          1
 2014    2     3
 2015    3    12
 2016    3    48
 2017    2   144
```

The values in the first two columns are hard-coded, but the cells in V2 are calculated using a formula like this, which is copied down from the first cell:

```
=IF(A2="",1,B1*(1+A2))
```

I've tried making a function in R that will make column V2, by running through each row, and cumulatively multiplying the values in V1, using something like  cumprod(1:i), but I can't get anything that will work correctly.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the right idea with `cumprod`:

```
# Create the data
Year <- 2012:2017
V1 <- c('', '', 2, 3, 3, 2)
df <- data.frame(Year, V1, stringsAsFactors = F)

# Make sure the V1 column contains only integers
df$V1 <- as.integer(df$V1)
df$V1[is.na(df$V1)] <- 0

# Calculate the product
df$V2 <- cumprod(df$V1 + 1)
```

Result:

```
  Year V1  V2
1 2012  0   1
2 2013  0   1
3 2014  2   3
4 2015  3  12
5 2016  3  48
6 2017  2 144
```